# How to access WCF WebServiceHost endpoint with HTTPS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, visual-studio, wcf-binding

I have successfully created `WCF self-hosted HTTP` web service. I use `webserviceHost` to create this service. I didn't make any changes in `web.config` file. Here is my code:

Instance.cs:

```
 [OperationContract, WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/getstatus/", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool getstatus();
```

service.cs:

```
 public bool getstatus()
    {
        return true;
    }
```

BindingWS.cs

```
 void bindservice()
    {
        try
        {
            m_running = true;
            // Start the host
            m_serviceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Swiper.cs), new Uri(http://localhost:8083"));
            ServiceEndpoint ep = m_serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(Instace.cs), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
            m_serviceHost.Open();
            while (m_running)
            {
                // Wait until thread is stopped
                Thread.Sleep(SleepTime);
            }

            // Stop the host
            m_serviceHost.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            if (m_serviceHost != null)
            {
                m_serviceHost.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Above code works fine to run `WCF` at `Htpp`. but how i convert it into `HTTPS`. I followes so many blogs but didn't got anything. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: what about just changing the adress? `new Uri(https://localhost:8083")`

Comment: No, It can't. Because there are a lot of things to do like `certificates`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to manually register the certificate against the port number you are using in your host. Here is some details on how to accomplish that

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx

**UPDATE 21/2/13:**

Provided that you have registered your certificate for the domain as described above you should be able to get this working by making some adjustments to the code above. Here is some sample code using a console application as a host. HTH.

```
    using (var serviceHost = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Swiper), new Uri("https://localhost:8083")))
        {
            var secureWebHttpBinding = new WebHttpBinding(WebHttpSecurityMode.Transport) { Name = "secureHttpWeb" };
            serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISwiper), secureWebHttpBinding, "");
            serviceHost.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Service running...");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop service.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Stop the host
            serviceHost.Close();
        }
```

Comment: I don't have any problem to deal with certificates, but what changes i have to make in above code

Comment: @AmitPal can you post your configuration. I assume you are hosting this in a console app?

Comment: It is available at here: http://pastebin.com/96x8Y4nU

BTW, This web service is all created by program (not from config file).

Comment: @AmitPal the link is broken.